# Choppy audio / audio stutter on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS Intel HDA

Tags: 16.04, sound, hdmi, hda-intel

Please help! I've been struggling with this for months. I have tried several flavors and version of Ubuntu and it issue persists.

Problem description:
Audio playback from any application, whether the local media player, streaming video via Chromium or Firefox, even from the CLI via "speaker-test"(I used the sine wave generator), is choppy, or stutters.

I have an Intel NUC model D54250WYKH, which is an older i5 with integrated Intel HD5000 video.

While on *youtube.com* or playing an MP3, the audio is interrupted by a stuttering effect. (Follow the links for a sample of my specific problem)
[A Sample of my specific audio problem](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Aeo569pb9BM)
!

It is worth noting the the analog HDA Intel PCH works flawlessly.  It's just the default HDA INTEL HDMI that is problematic, and that's how I'd like to continue using it.

I used to have the problem before I tried to switch Ubuntu flavors and I scoured the internet and found a solution, but I cannot seem to find it again.  I spent months on and off trying different things.

---

**Here's an output from aplay -l:**

```
aplay -l

**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****

card 0: HDMI [HDA Intel HDMI], device 3: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0

card 0: HDMI [HDA Intel HDMI], device 7: HDMI 1 [HDMI 1]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0

card 1: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 0: ALC283 Analog [ALC283 Analog]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

---

**Here's an output from aplay -L:**

```
aplay -L

default
    Playback/recording through the PulseAudio sound server

null
    Discard all samples (playback) or generate zero samples (capture)

pulse
    PulseAudio Sound Server

hdmi:CARD=HDMI,DEV=0
    HDA Intel HDMI, HDMI 0
    HDMI Audio Output

hdmi:CARD=HDMI,DEV=1
    HDA Intel HDMI, HDMI 1
    HDMI Audio Output

dmix:CARD=HDMI,DEV=3
    HDA Intel HDMI, HDMI 0
    Direct sample mixing device

dmix:CARD=HDMI,DEV=7
    HDA Intel HDMI, HDMI 1
    Direct sample mixing device

dsnoop:CARD=HDMI,DEV=3
    HDA Intel HDMI, HDMI 0
    Direct sample snooping device

dsnoop:CARD=HDMI,DEV=7
    HDA Intel HDMI, HDMI 1
    Direct sample snooping device

hw:CARD=HDMI,DEV=3
    HDA Intel HDMI, HDMI 0
    Direct hardware device without any conversions

hw:CARD=HDMI,DEV=7
    HDA Intel HDMI, HDMI 1
    Direct hardware device without any conversions

plughw:CARD=HDMI,DEV=3
    HDA Intel HDMI, HDMI 0
    Hardware device with all software conversions

plughw:CARD=HDMI,DEV=7
    HDA Intel HDMI, HDMI 1
    Hardware device with all software conversions

sysdefault:CARD=PCH
    HDA Intel PCH, ALC283 Analog
    Default Audio Device

front:CARD=PCH,DEV=0
    HDA Intel PCH, ALC283 Analog
    Front speakers

surround21:CARD=PCH,DEV=0
    HDA Intel PCH, ALC283 Analog
    2.1 Surround output to Front and Subwoofer speakers

surround40:CARD=PCH,DEV=0
    HDA Intel PCH, ALC283 Analog
    4.0 Surround output to Front and Rear speakers

surround41:CARD=PCH,DEV=0
    HDA Intel PCH, ALC283 Analog
    4.1 Surround output to Front, Rear and Subwoofer speakers

surround50:CARD=PCH,DEV=0
    HDA Intel PCH, ALC283 Analog
    5.0 Surround output to Front, Center and Rear speakers

surround51:CARD=PCH,DEV=0
    HDA Intel PCH, ALC283 Analog
    5.1 Surround output to Front, Center, Rear and Subwoofer speakers

surround71:CARD=PCH,DEV=0
    HDA Intel PCH, ALC283 Analog
    7.1 Surround output to Front, Center, Side, Rear and Woofer speakers

dmix:CARD=PCH,DEV=0
    HDA Intel PCH, ALC283 Analog
    Direct sample mixing device

dsnoop:CARD=PCH,DEV=0
    HDA Intel PCH, ALC283 Analog
    Direct sample snooping device

hw:CARD=PCH,DEV=0
    HDA Intel PCH, ALC283 Analog
    Direct hardware device without any conversions

plughw:CARD=PCH,DEV=0
    HDA Intel PCH, ALC283 Analog
    Hardware device with all software conversions
```

---

**Things that I have tried:**

- in the file */etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf*, I most recently added this:

  ```
  options snd-hda-intel vid=8086 pid=8ca0 snoop=0
  ```
- in the file */etc/pulse/default.pa*, I most recently I tried the commented out this change:

  ```
  load-module module-udev-detect tsched=0
  ```
- I have tried a few others, but reverted back...

---

Please help!

~Eric

Comment: so, did you solve it?